# XFCE, TTY, blank screen, not working shortcuts

Tags: xfce, shortcuts, tty

I've got a strange problem with keyboard shortcuts.
After turning on my computer (or rebooting), and logging in, shortcuts don't work. To get them working, I have to log out and log in again. Then everything is all right.
There's another problem. I have access to TTY-s 1-6 only just after reboot (and logging in for the first time). When I log out (to make Xfce shortcuts working), I loose access to my TTY-s. There's a blank screen instead.

I think that there might be a key conflict. But I don't use any shortcut combination which uses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> at the same time.
I have a NVIDIA graphics card.

I put a line:

```
Option "HandleSpecialKeys" "always"
```

in the section "ServerLayout" (I tried before in ServerFlags) in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
but it didn't helped (firstly I wanted to fix ttys, being unaware of desktop shortcuts problem)

An issue with blank screen on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> happens also after waking up from a suspend state. To get access to TTY 1-6 after loosing it, I have to reboot my computer.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found out how to make TTY-s working after a suspend, login etc. Firstly, I thought that the reason is the Power Manager. Actually, the reason was quite different. 
Installing xserver-xorg-video-nouveau and connected packages, instead of NVidia Current driver, helped. I had Nvidia driver version 304, and I'm not sure about the new version, 310; if it's better or not. 
As far as shortcuts are concerned, I've also replaced in my keyboard shortcut file (/home/mpd/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml) all "Control" entries with "Primary".